# Not able to cpature fingerprint using Morpho scanner device in android

Tags: java, android, error-code

Device I'm Using: **Morpho Device**

**Issue:**

When I am trying to capture fingerprint, device getting disconnected automatically and shows `error code 100`  `Invalid PidOptions input.  XML should strictly  adhere to spec.`   and after changing values of it shows `error code 140` and `error code 999`
this is `xml` String which Im sending to the Intent

```
String responseXml =
        "<PidOptions ver=\"1.0\"> " +
                "<Opts env = \"P\" fCount=\"1\" fType=\"0\"|fType=\"1\"|fType=\"2\"" +
                " iCount=\"\" iType=\"\" pCount=\"\" pType=\"\" pTimeout=\"\" format=\"0\"" +
                " pidVer=\"2.0\" timeout=\"10000\" otp=\"\" wadh=\"\" posh=\"\"/><Demo></Demo><CustOpts>" +
                "<!-- no application should hard code these and should be configured on app or AUA servers. \n" +
                "These parameters can be used for any custom application authentication or for other \n" +
                "configuration parameters. Device providers can differentiate their service in the market by \n" +
                "enabling advanced algorithms that applications can take advantage of. --> <Param \n" +
                "name=\"\" value=\"\" /></CustOpts></PidOptions>";
private static final int AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST = 0;
```

This is `Intent`

```
  Intent intent = new
                    Intent("in.gov.uidai.rdservice.fp.CAPTURE");
            intent.setPackage("com.scl.rdservice");
            intent.putExtra("PID_OPTIONS",responseXml);
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST);
```

and this is Activity result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); if
    (requestCode == AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            if (b != null) {
                String pidData = b.getString("PID_DATA");
                Toast.makeText(this, "pidData"+pidData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // in this varaible you will get Pid data
                String dnc = b.getString("DNC", "");
                Toast.makeText(this, "disconnected"+dnc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// you will get value in this variable when your finger
              //  print device not connected
                String dnr = b.getString("DNR", "");
                //Toast.makeText(this, "connected"+dnr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // you will get value in this variable when
                //your finger print device not registered.

                txt.setText(pidData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you able to solve it?